# How to observe a live data throughout the app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have created a live data which basically update itself whenever there is change in network. I have to observe that change throughout the app. So My question is which is the better approach to do this ?

1. by observing the live data forever in the App class

   connectivityManager.observeForever {
   IS_NETWORK_CONNECTED = it
   }
2. by observing the live data using the lifecycle of the app

   connectivityManager.observe(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get(), Observer {
   })

If there any problems with these approaches? If yes, then what should do to observe it ?

My live data class

```
class ConnectivityManager(context: Context) : LiveData<Boolean>() {

  private lateinit var networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
  private val cm = context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
  private val validNetworks: MutableSet<Network> = HashSet()

  private fun checkValidNetworks() {
    postValue(validNetworks.size > 0)
  }

  override fun onActive() {
    networkCallback = createNetworkCallback()
    val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
      .addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
      .build()
    cm.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback)
  }

  override fun onInactive() {
    cm.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
  }

  private fun createNetworkCallback() = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
      val networkCapabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
      val hasInternetCapability = networkCapabilities?.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
      if (hasInternetCapability == true)
        checkValidNetworks()
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
      validNetworks.remove(network)
      checkValidNetworks()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you do not need `ProcessLifecycleOwner` here you can just observe it with components LifeCycle . a better approach would be create base classes(for activity fragment and View model) and obeserve in Base classes and expose the state from there to all its children .

Comment: Can you please add some code sample also